# Access row group's row and edit column value in ag grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to access row which has group so I can edit the column values there. I tried

```
node.addEventListener('expandedChanged', ({ node, api }) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (node.expanded && node.level === 0) {
                node.gridApi
                    .getRowNode(node.id)
                    .setDataValue('date an ', '')
            }
        }, 1000)
    })
```

I am not able to get RowNode by this.

[image]

When on level 0 and node.group === true and node.expanded === false, I want to show date on column for which I have written custom renderer. But when I expand level 0, I want to hide date on level 0 and show date on level 1 only. The problem is cell/row doesn't rerender and hence doesnt check condition in custom cell renderer.

How to edit the column value on level 0 when node.group === true and node.expanded === true?

Comment: could u provide any plunk or stackblitz - just to play around for the solution?